# AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute '_Student__marks'

Tags: python, oop, private-members

gives me this error when I run this code

```
class Info:
  def __init__(self,name,Id,mobile):
    self.name=name
    self.Id=Id
    self.mobile=mobile
 
 
class Student(Info):
  def data1(self,name, Id, mobile):
    super().__init__(name, Id, mobile)
 
    self.__marks={'Math': 140,'Software':130, 'Physics':90}
 
  def get_grades(self,courses):
    if courses in self.__marks:
      return self.__marks[courses]
    else:
      print('not available')
 
class Proffessor(Info):
  def data2(self,name, Id, mobile,salary):
    self.__salary=salary
 
    super().__init__(name, Id, mobile)
 
 
    s=Student('Ali', 77, 345678)
    #print(s.get_grades('Math'))
    print(s.get_grades(courses='Math'))
```

I tried to print the name of the course alone and also didn't work

Comment: are you sure that's python? you need to paste it in exactly as it is in your text editor.  without the newlines and indentations, impossible to tell where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I took a guess at the formatting. It looks like the init for your `Student` class is called `data1` for some reason, so unless that gets called, `__marks` will be undefined.

Comment: it is I just don't know how to right it here the website keeps reformatting it into this

Comment: This code produces *no errors* (since this is just a bunch of class definitions, which you never use). Please always provide a [mcve]

Comment: But note, the only place you assign to `self.__marks` is in `def data1`, where you also call `super().__init__`... is that method really supposed to be `def data1`?

Comment: click on the {} in the editor and then paste your code in. should work fine.
Alternatively, type 3 backticks, then paste code, then 3 more backticks.

Comment: Gotta say, I don't see the attribute `_student__marks` defined anywhere...

Comment: I think that has to do with how python handles "private variables". It uses name mangling so that they can't be accessed normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
def data1(self,name, Id, mobile):
```

with

```
def __init__(self,name, Id, mobile):
```

so that python recognizes the method as a constructor, and not a class method. That way, when you reference `self.__marks` in `get_grades` it will be initialized. That is, the constructor will run as soon as you create the student object, whereas `data1` won't run unless you call it. Because `data1` doesn't run, the `self.__marks` variable is never initialized.